# Where can I find other Heide Knights that can drop a Heide's Spear?

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls-2-sotfs

I am debuting a spear build, love the move set. However, since it is my first play-through, I am limited to the normal spear.

Arriving at Heide's Tower of Fire, I was happy to see a Heide Knight, whose armor I *love* and who has a corresponding spear!

However, it seems that the spear can only be dropped by spear-wielding Heide Knights, and the only spear-wielding one I found (not far from the Dragonslayer Boss room) have stopped respawning without dropping it.

As it is my first play, I don't have any Bonfire Ascetics, and am quite wary of using them. Is there any other place I can access quickly with a spear-wielding Heide Knight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Wiki](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Heide+Spear) says that one knight in Sinners Rise (SOTFS only) has a 100% drop chance for this spear.  I would say that this is the quickest way to get one, but whether or not reaching this area early in the game I'm not sure.

The other location you can find spear wielding knights is the Lost Bastille, and Heide's Tower of Flames (SOTFS only and again, I'm not sure if you can reach these areas early on having never played).  According to the page for the [Knights](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Heide+Knight) they only respawn in the Tower of Flames, all others knights do not.  If you find a spear-wielding knight in there, I would try and farm it.

Comment: Well, it seems I'll have to go to Sinners Rise, hope I can make it throught the Lost Bastille. I have already despawned the only spear wielding one I found in HToF, so farming it is not a solution until I can find a Bonfire Ascetics.

Answer (score 2):

While Timmy Jim's answer is correct for the locations, you can simply go back to Majula and join the *Company of Champions* covenant. It makes enemies respawn infinitely, allowing you to keep farming the one at Heide's Tower of Fire. However, it also makes the game a bit harder and restrict online help.

You can read more on the [wiki](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Company+of+Champions).